# Why do small samples have big variances?

Tags: variance

I am trying to understand why they say that small samples have big variances. For example, suppose the population variance of some variable is 100. I take 5 samples and the variance is 156 ... in this case, the sample variance is bigger than the population variance. I then take another sample of 5, and its possible that the variance is now 21.

Therefore, is it more correct to say that the absoloute value of the difference in sample variance and population variance is bigger for small samples compared to big samples? EX: big samples reduce the effect of outliers on variance calculation?

The way I see it, small sample sizes might overestimate the variance or underestimate the variance ... but the amount of overestimation/underestimation is bigger in smaller samples compared to bigger samples?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything special about variance here: when you compute some property of a sample, that property will inevitably vary about its population value: sometimes above, sometimes below.  Moreover, provided the population property is well-defined and finite, the amount of that variation is smaller with larger samples.

Comment: `I am trying to understand why they say that small samples have big variances.` Who says that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the variation of the mean as an example.

The sampling variation of the mean is

$$ \sigma^2 /n $$

And our estimate of the sampling variation is

$$ s^2 / n $$

Now, assume that our estimate of $\sigma^2$ is the sample sample to sample.  You see that smaller samples *quite literally have larger sampling variation*.  Not to beat a dead horse, but assuming two studies are run with different sample sizes, $n_1$ and $n_2$, such that $n_1 < n_2$, then assuming the sample variance is the same in both studies, the sampling variation is larger in study 1 because

$$ n_1 < n_2 $$

$$ \dfrac{1}{n_2} < \dfrac{1}{n_1} $$

$$ \dfrac{s^2}{n_2} < \dfrac{s^2}{n_1} $$

$$ \mbox{sampling variation in study 2} < \mbox{sampling variation in study 1} $$

What this means practically is that results from smaller samples tend to be more extreme than from large samples.  This is what people mean when people say "small samples have big variances".

Comment: but is it absoloute value large difference .... or actual overestimation?

Comment: btw i remember you posted a comment on a q i asked about odds ratio for two variables. can u pls write more about it??? i have been studying this for weeks can just cant understand it! even chatgpt is not helping me lol!

Comment: It is larger over/underestimation - the absolute size of the variance has nothing to do with the sample size, it is a population characteristic. The larger the sample the closer the estimate will be to the population.

Comment: @PBulls Standard error is, at least a little loosely speaking, a quantification of by how much you will tend to overestimate or underestimate a parameter.

Answer (score 7):

When people say things like

> small samples have big variances

they do not mean that every small sample has a large variance. That would be wrong and really kind of silly. Clearly, a particular small sample may have a large variance or a small one.

So, what do they mean? It's hard to know without context. However, one thing they might mean is that if you take (say) 10 small samples and 10 large samples from the same population, the small samples will vary more. E.g.

```
set.seed(1234)
pop <- rnorm(10000) #Standard normal
mean(sample(pop, 5)) #0.37
mean(sample(pop, 5)) #0.05
mean(sample(pop, 5))#0.19
mean(sample(pop, 5)) #-0.55
mean(sample(pop, 5)) #-0.62

mean(sample(pop, 100)) #-0.03
mean(sample(pop, 100)) #0.00
mean(sample(pop, 100))#0.07
mean(sample(pop, 100)) #-0.02
mean(sample(pop, 100)) #0.09
```

The former vary much more than the latter.